# Match One of Many interfaces for Promise response

Tags: typescript

i've got an API handler that returns a promise of a `type`. Depending on the API response, the object returned could of one of the following interfaces:

```
export interface Event {
  statusCode: number
}

export interface CreateEvent extends Event {
  data: Object
}

export interface Forbidden {
  message: string
}
```

I can't seem to get the types right when I run my tests for either of these types. All return something like `this value doesn't exist on type:` where it's a missing value from Forbidden when it was a Successful response"

I expected:

```
type ApiResponse = Forbidden | Event | CreateEvent
```

or

```
export enum ApiResponse {CreateEvent, Forbidden, Event}
```

When setting the api function return type to:

```
callApi = (event: Event): Promise<ApiResponse>   => {...}
```

I'm not sure what `ts` is expecting for this. Seems like pretty basic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If a function returns 1 of three things, you will need a Type Guard or Type Assertion function to figure out which of the three it was.

Comment: What does that look like?